Is there an accepted way to use System.IO classes on a OneDrive file?
This is a question I've been curious about for years. It's not blocking me at all; I'd just like to know the answer.
I have some .NET Framework apps for personal use that want to read and write text files at known locations relative to my OneDrive root. Because I'm lazy, I use the File, StreamReader/StreamWriter classes on the local clone and let the OneDrive service do the rest. On my systems, I know it is rooted at %USERPROFILE%\OneDrive, but while perfectly workable it feels clumsy, because (unless something has changed) any given installation can configure its local root somewhere else.
Simple question: Is there a system query that will let me determine the actual root directory so that I can code the local file open "properly"? This question had more salience when we were switching from SkyDrive to OneDrive, and I had differently named roots on different systems during the changeover.
More complex question: is there a way of connecting to the online OneDrive file through a Stream object (or otherwise) that I can then manipulate using the simple I/O classes?
I looked for the OneDrive root in the registry. I also started looking at the OneDrive REST APIs documentation, but it's not clear if it provides what I want. If it indeed does, then an answer of "don't be so lazy" would be perfectly understandable.
I see some potential solutions in the Windows.Storage namespace, but that seems to be UWP only.

Oh, for heaven's sake. The answer to the first question is %ONEDRIVE%. I saw it in my envars but thought I had put it there myself and forgot.
I'd still like to know if I can connect a Stream to the server directly.
